# how to import multiple relationships files (file groups) into neo4j with neo4j-import?

Tags: csv, neo4j

[this example in the neo4j docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/import-tool/#import-tool-multiple-input-files-example) shows multiple groups of nodes files, but only one group of relationships files.

`neo4j_home$ ./bin/neo4j-import --into path_to_target_directory --nodes "movies4-header.csv,movies4-part1.csv,movies4-part2.csv" --nodes "actors4-header.csv,actors4-part1.csv,actors4-part2.csv" --relationships "roles4-header.csv,roles4-part1.csv,roles4-part2.csv"`

what is the syntax to import multiple relationships files into neo4j with neo4j-import?

I can imagine extending the example to also have a `DIRECTED_IN` relationship type, which would be described in a file called **directed-in4.csv**

then, I could imagine that the  call to `neo4j-import` would look like this:

`neo4j_home$ ./bin/neo4j-import --into path_to_target_directory --nodes "movies4-header.csv,movies4-part1.csv,movies4-part2.csv" --nodes "actors4-header.csv,actors4-part1.csv,actors4-part2.csv" --relationships "roles4-header.csv,roles4-part1.csv,roles4-part2.csv" --relationships directed-in4.csv`

with the additional `--relationships directed-in4.csv` tacked on at the end. Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears that specifying multiple relationships does work like this:

> neo4j_home$ ./bin/neo4j-import --into path_to_target_directory --nodes
>   "movies4-header.csv,movies4-part1.csv,movies4-part2.csv" --nodes
>   "actors4-header.csv,actors4-part1.csv,actors4-part2.csv"
>   --relationships "roles4-header.csv,roles4-part1.csv,roles4-part2.csv" --relationships directed-in4.csv

with the additional `--relationships` argument

Comment: here's what I ended up with, for the curious https://github.com/micahstubbs/blockbuilder-graph-search-index/blob/master/load-csv-graph-into-neo4j.sh#L14

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17085208)

Comment: thanks for fixing the code sample formatting Ichigo :-)